# JSON-P + RESTful API

Tags: jquery, json, api, url, rest

noob here. I can't not get my alert to show up with this code. Can someone please point me in the right direction to make this pull from the json feed? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">    </script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.getJSON("http://api.shoplocal.com/api/2012.1/json/getpromotions.aspx?campaignid=86107c2cdcc39561&citystatezip=46225" + "&campaignid=",         function(feed) {
    alert("Symbol: " + feed.content.collection.data.image);
});
</script></body>
</html>
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "content": {
        "collection": {
            "data": {
                "code": "RC-130127",
                "customimagedescription": "",
                "customimagelocation": "",
                "displayorder": "0",
                "featuredpromotion": "N",
                "identifier": "01\/27 Circular",
                "image": "http:\/\/akimages.shoplocal.com\/dyn_rppi\/140.0.90.0\/RobertsCamera\/large\/130127_Pg1_cqu82.jpg",
                "postenddate": "2\/2\/2013 12:00:00 AM",
                "poststartdate": "1\/27\/2013 12:00:00 AM",
                "previewenddate": "",
                "previewstartdate": "",
                "promotionchildtypeid": "",
                "promotionchildtypename": "",
                "promotionid": "85347",
                "promotionmessage": "",
                "retailerid": "12847",
                "retailername": "Roberts Camera",
                "saleenddate": "2\/2\/2013 12:00:00 AM",
                "salestartdate": "1\/27\/2013 12:00:00 AM",
                "tag": "RC-130127",
                "title": "01\/27 Circular",
                "typeid": "1",
                "vo": "promotion"
            },
            "vo": "promotion"
        },
        "date": "1\/30\/2013 12:28:52 PM"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the json here.

Comment: I highly doubt all of the data returned contains no arrays and is only objects. When you console.log() the returned value, how many of them say Array[1]?

Answer (score 1):

Add `&callback=?` to the end of your URL to trigger JSONP, otherwise you'll get a XMLHttpRequest crossdomain error:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.shoplocal.com/api/2012.1/json/getpromotions.aspx?campaignid=86107c2cdcc39561&citystatezip=46225&campaignid=&callback=?",
               function(feed) {
    alert("Symbol: " + feed.content.collection.data.image);
});
```

See the [JSONP section](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) of the getJSON docs for more info.

I've also just noticed you're pulling in jQuery v1.3.2. This solution may not work for a version that old, [but it does work with newer versions](http://jsfiddle.net/JPxkG/).

Comment: This works! Yeah, I need to update my code snippets. (v1.3.2 has been in my lib for a long time. ) Thanks for your help Samsquanch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons you are not able to call a resource using the Ajax functionalities like (getJSON, ajax, post, get) outside the domain of your application.

Take a look on your javascript console to see the issue.

[How to call external url in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613310/how-to-call-external-url-in-jquery)

This link will clarify everything.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589940#14601205) for details as to why you should not be considering JSONP for use with supposedly "RESTful" APIs. In short, use CORS instead.